Learn from Scratch the fundamental maths used in economic theory in order to pass the civil service of economists entry exams
I want to enter a Civil Service body of social security economists and to pass the exams I need to learn from scratch fundamental mathematics used to solve typical exercises in micro and macroeconomic theory.
I am a political scientist and I have studied basic aspects of statistics and economics that are part of the syllabus of the oppositions, however, in my training as a political scientist, the issues of economics and statistics are focused on people with very basic levels of mathematics (without knowledge of calculus, for example) and focus on the practical (for example, practical exercises on linear regression or statistical inference but using software such as R, and without going into the details of the mathematical theory that underlies them, such as integrals to calculate areas under the curve in statistical distributions).
However, in the exams that I want to pass, I will be required to present some topics of micro and macroeconomic theory with a certain level of detail, for which, for example, knowing how to understand and calculate derivatives is essential. I could do a more basic presentation focusing on explaining the concepts with graphs and some algebra, but in the practical exams I will be asked for exercises with functions to solve theoretical problems (for example, calculating the deadweight loss of welfare due to a monopoly given some data , or, given a production technology dependent on K and L, calculate the expansion path equation for given factor prices).
I would like to know if you think it is an impossible undertaking for someone who is already an adult and who has not seen mathematics since he was 15 years old. My idea is to have some type of private teacher, but I would have to learn practically from scratch, first the basic algebra and then the mathematics necessary to face this type of exercises (which implies knowing how to do derivatives, for example).
Do you think it is possible in 1 or 2 years of full-time study to do this mathematical learning or maybe I should forget about it?
If it seemed feasible, where would you start? Is there an affordable book to learn the basic mathematics necessary to understand economic theory well?
thank you.

There is always mathematics for economists by Simon and Blume. Solutions for exercises and the book can be found online.
